# Unreal Engine 5.1 Visual Studio 2022, пропадают классы после перезагрузки проекта

Tags: unreal-engine-5

После перезагрузки проекта пропадают папки с созданными C++ классами, при этом если попытаться создать новый класс то будет писать что уже с таким именем существует, если попытаться открыть блюпринт класс наследованный от C++ класса который пропал, то напишет что класса не существует. Ещё не могу в самой Visual Studio забильдить проект (build project) появляется куча ошибок которые пропадают через несколько секунд, получается только через сам Unreal. Ещё intellisence не высвечивает подсказки всех библиотек Unreal engine (при #include нету директории Camera/, но при этом код компилируется если указать эту директорию)

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае помогла принудительная компиляция при запуске проекта, которая включается через меню Edit -> Editor Preferences -> Loading & Saving (General) -> Startup и в пункте Force Compilation at Startup указать значение True (поставив галочку).[image: Уточняющее изображение]